# Is this the best practice for routing in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance

I'm pretty much an amateur when it comes to Rails. I got this to work, however I feel like the code is not efficient enough.

Is there any way to speed this up? And also it this how a professional would do it?

Controller

```
def mark_read
    @topic = Topic.find(params[:id])
    @topic.mark_as_read! :for => current_user
    redirect_to user_path(current_user.slug) 
end

def mark_all_read
    Topic.mark_as_read! :all, :for => current_user
    redirect_to user_path(current_user.slug) 
end
```

Routes

```
resources :users do
  member do
    post :mark_read
    post :mark_all_read
  end
end
```

View

```
<% if current_user.id == @user.id %>
<%= link_to "Mark all as read", mark_all_read_user_path, :method=> :post %>

<h4> List of posts unread by you </h4>
<% @unread.each do |topic| %>
<% if @user.following?(Product.find(topic.product_id)) %>
<li> <%= topic.title %> <%= link_to "Mark as read", mark_read_user_path(topic),    :method=> :post %> </li>
<% end %> 
<% end %>
```

Is there someway that I could call an action in the controller without a route? I feel it would make the workflow neater.

Comment: I think its not the best practice to add such actions to the user's controller. You could try concerns if you are using rails 4 or just create a topics_controller which includes all the actions related to  Topic model.

Comment: @Swaathi  I have the same question. I worked with cakephp and when you create an action `show_all` in controller `Car` inmediatelly you have the path `localhost/Car/show_all` ... I'm looking some like this in rails

Comment: @mohameddiaa27 the "mark_read" and "mark_all_read" are actions in the User controller. And this view is the User show page. I was just concerned if I need to create a route every time I need to access an action. I feel it makes the app very vulnerable since the URL scheme is exposed.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is no. You can not have access any action in the controller unless it has a route, or its a CRUD generated by default, for example:

```
resources :articles
```

generates

```
Controller#Action
    articles GET    /articles(.:format)          articles#index
             POST   /articles(.:format)          articles#create
 new_article GET    /articles/new(.:format)      articles#new
edit_article GET    /articles/:id/edit(.:format) articles#edit
     article GET    /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#show
             PATCH  /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#update
             PUT    /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#update
             DELETE /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#destroy
```

Comment: The "mark_read" and "mark_as_read" do have routes and respective actions in the controller. I just don't want to create a route every time I need to access an action in a controller.

Comment: Actually the only work around to reduce the custom routes, is to map each action to its CRUD type, in this case `mark_read` can be replaced by update. But this is not the best practice, routes are the open doors to your app, they expose methods to be actions, and its meant to be like that for security.

Comment: But if they expose the URL and the action name doesn't it take a hit on security? It is going to make it more vulnerable right?

Comment: You expose the url of a method that does a specific function. You handle authentication and authorization in the controller. ex: `mark_all_read` will mark the topics read for the current_user. imagine rails without routes, i can access the sign_in method, i would sign in only with my id.

Comment: That's true. But is there any way to access an action without the need of a route?

Comment: no way, and for the CRUD actions, you can even disable the unused ones, by: `resources :articles, only: [:new, :create]`